# Make clickable words in large text, efficiently - SwiftUI, iOS, macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

**Background**

I am building an ebook-reader application whereas I want some words in the text to be clickable, to access further information about the specific word clicked.

**Objective**
[image]
The words "sample" and "illustrate" would be clickable in this case. Ideally they would behave like real buttons: get lighter as the user touches them, return to normal when touch ends and allow me to act on the click of the word aka. do something programmatically.

**Steps taken**

`SwiftUI`'s `Text("")` now offers us to use links, like this:

`Text("This is a [sample](ebook://sample) text to [illustrate](ebook://illustrate) my objective.")`

With `DeepLink`s, I could catch those link calls in the app itself. This approach seems rather cumbersome and I would be using it in a non-intuitive way. Additionally, I can't change the background color of the clickable words, they would always appear as links, which isn't a great user experience.

*My question: is there a better way to do this?*

Comment: There are different ways sure, but better depends on too many things that are based on circumstance and opinion. Which is out of scope for SO.

Comment: Would you please give me one or two keywords so I can look up the APIs, a hint into the right direction would suffice

Comment: SwiftUI tappable Text, right here in SO. Will give you many answers, especially the ones pre-WWDC21 where attributed text was introduced for SwiftUI. Request for APIs is also out of scope in SO.